# How to get rid of emojis in dataset

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

I am using the disaster tweets dataset from Kaggle for NLP. I am cleaning the data and trying to get rid of the emojis. The dataset is so big that I can't pick every single one of the emojis separately and drop them. Does anyone know how to get rid of them all at once?

This is code that I've tried but doesn't work:

```
def remove_emoji(string):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile(
        "["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
        u"\U00002500-\U00002BEF"  # chinese char
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
        u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937"
        u"\U00010000-\U0010ffff"
        u"\u2640-\u2642"
        u"\u2600-\u2B55"
        u"\u200d"
        u"\u23cf"
        u"\u23e9"
        u"\u231a"
        u"\ufe0f"  # dingbats
        u"\u3030"
        "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return emoji_pattern.sub(r'', string)
```

Comment: When posting, it's best to elaborate on "doesn't work." Does it not remove any of the emojis? Does it only leave some? Etc.

Comment: Also, note that you shouldn't need to compile the regex each time your function is called. Perhaps the value is cached and that's not too inefficient, but either way it's not necessary.

Comment: The `u"..."` prefix is accepted for backwards compatibility, but doesn't do anything useful in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

For clearing your data, you have to pass through full dataframe which is O(n), so in any case you going to pick every single tweet and drop emojis in it.

To clear the data efficiently, we can utilize the parallel_apply method from the pandarallel library. This method allows for parallel computation, resulting in a significant speedup.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True)

# assuming your dataframe is called 'df' and the column you want to remove emojis from is 'tweet'

df['tweet_filtered'] = df['tweet'].parallel_apply(remove_emoji)
```

Comment: thanks! when I run the parallel_apply code chunk it doesn't seem to do anything to my dataset. Maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: Send part of the code where you define your dataset and how you run parallel_apply

Comment: I was able to get it to work! Thank you!!

Comment: I am glad to help, I will be grateful for the rate of this answer